how to add dalvik vm in android project
Im trying to create a game core and everything is done exept compiler. I tryed to to like that:

package com.ccs.gencorelite.compiler;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProjectCompiler {

    public static void compileProject(String projectPath, String outputPath) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "aapt", "package", "-f",
                    "-M", projectPath + "/AndroidManifest.xml",
AndroidManifest.xml
                    "-S", projectPath + "/res", 
                    "-I", "file:///resources/android.jar",                    "-F", outputPath + "/app.apk" 
            );

            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process process = builder.start();

            // Очікування завершення процесу
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();

            // Перевірка статусу завершення
            if (exitCode == 0) {
                System.out.println("Проєкт успішно скомпільовано.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Помилка під час компіляції проєкту.");
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


After some errors that i have not permissions to compile.
I rewrite this class added some folders to assets folder:
build-tools34,
platforms,
platform-tools,
sdk34
and this class is have like this view:
package com.ccs.gencorelite.compiler;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ProjectCompiler {


    public static void compileJavaFiles(String projectPath) {

        String javaCompilerPath = "file:///android_asset/compiler/bt34/javac";
        String[] javacCmd = { javaCompilerPath, "-d", projectPath + "/bin", projectPath + "/src/**/*.java" };
        executeCommand(javacCmd);
    }

    public static void compileResources(String projectPath) {
        String aaptPath = "file:///android_asset/compiler/bt34/aapt";
        String[] aaptCmd = { aaptPath, "package", "-f", "-m", "-J", projectPath + "/gen", "-S", projectPath + "/res", "-I", "file:///android_resources/android.jar" };
        executeCommand(aaptCmd);
    }

    public static void convertToDalvikBytecode(String projectPath) {
        String dxPath = "file:///android_asset/compiler/bt34/dx";
        String[] dxCmd = { dxPath, "--dex", "--output=" + projectPath + "/bin/classes.dex", projectPath + "/bin" };
        executeCommand(dxCmd);
    }

    public static void executeCommand(String[] command) {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

And i have errors about this class:
`
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:///android_assets/compiler/bt34/javac": error=2, No such file or directory
2024-05-09 22:14:26.305 28386-28386 System.err              com.ccs.gencorelite                  W  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:///android_assets/compiler/bt34/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
2024-05-09 22:14:26.312 28386-28386 System.err              com.ccs.gencorelite                  W  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:///android_assets/compiler/bt34/dx": error=2, No such file or directory
`

Are you saying that only these two Java files have compilation failures? Are there any Java files that compile successfully? The error output does not suggest that there's anything wrong with the code in those two files.

@SmellyCat, i can't run compiler even thought, cuz no apps was found...
